# Ajax request returns success, but the server-side method is not being ran

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making an ajax call trying to get to the method of a class. The problem is that I do not get any result from the method of the class, but the success method of the ajax call is being ran as if everything is okay.

This is my ajax request:

```
;
$("#downloadBtn").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'allClients.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {action: 'downloader'},
        complete: function (result) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

My middle php file(the one that calls the method on $_POST[action] having value):

```
<?php

require_once 'common.php';

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    var_dump('was here');
    $myHttpHandlerClient->downloader();
} else {
    var_dump('here');
    $myHttpHandlerClient->viewAllClients($dataTransferClass);
}
```

My class that has the method inside:

```
class HttpHandlerClient extends HttpHandlerAbstract
{
private $clientsService;

public function __construct(clientsServiceInterface $clientsService)
{
    $this->clientsService = $clientsService;
}
public function downloader(/*DataTransferClass $dataClass*/)
{
    var_dump('here2');
    exit();
}
}
```

Sorry if this is duplicate, but I do not think so, my url is right(the file is in the root folder, the js file is in web/js/downloader.js) I get the success in the console, but I do not run the method.

Comment: what is coming back in the 'result' var in the complete method of the ajax call? That may give more clues to where/why it thinks everything worked as expected.

Comment: The jQuery ajax request assumes any response from your php file as success in your case. You can just check for the result coming from your allClients.php file.

For example:

if(result === '1'){console.log(success);} And other way around.

Comment: First things first: put your function reading 'action' inside try/catch statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php . Then, in catch statement, var_dump() or echo the error message (if there is problem with instance or something, it will just inform you about that). And at the end, console.log() that result in your ajax so you can see it.
Also, make sure you have $myHttpHandlerClient as instance of the object (I cannot see any declaration for that).
Ajax calls are pretty tricky to debug, that is why I think try/catch and console.log() are worth to try

Comment: And the best is if your response is JSON - that will be the easiest to read in console.
You can easily put some data into array, f.ex. $result['success']= true; $result['data'] = $use_some_amazing_method_returning_some_data; and then:
echo json_encode($result).

Comment: Thank you all, I was actually getting response. When I console logged the variable result I got my var_dumps from the php file.